# CoreLocation - visits monitoring

Tags: ios, core-location

I am facing issues when using visits monitoring service of coreLocation. When I use visits monitoring, the location update is inconsistent. What exactly is considered as a visit in corelocation?

This is how I start visits monitoring

```
self.manager.startMonitoringVisits()
```

I also have added all the CLLocationManagerDelegates.

Comment: What do you mean by "inconsistent"?

Comment: @Paulw11, sometimes I get visits update and sometimes even when i stay at a place for sometime, I am not getting any visit update.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/getting_the_user_s_location/using_the_visits_location_service) is quite ambiguous about what a visit is defined as. As reported by this [article](https://nshipster.com/core-location-in-ios-8/)

> lines get blurred at the edges of what is and what is not a visit. Ducking into a corner coffee shop for a minute might not trigger a visit, but waiting at a particularly long traffic light might. It’s likely that Apple will improve the quality of visit detection in future OS upgrades, but for now you might want to hold off on relying on CLVisit in favor of your own visit detection for use cases where it’s vital your data is as accurate as it can be.

CLVisit has a lot of shortcomings ranging from `arrivalDate` accuracy to `horizontalAccuracy` precision.
Instead of relying on `CLVisit`, try using the [Significant Location Change Service](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/getting_the_user_s_location/using_the_significant-change_location_service)

Answer (score 0):

I have an [app](https://apps.apple.com/au/app/where-was-i/id1523748405) in the store that uses visit tracking.

I find visit monitoring is pretty accurate. I have never had it detect a red light as a visit, for example. Comparing the reported visit times against an actual record of where I was is also pretty accurate.

The only real inaccuracy I have seen is the actual GPS coordinates and that is more a factor of being indoors or in an inner city area where gps accuracy is reduced.

While Apple does not document how their algorithm works, I suspect that they  uses more than just GPS when determining visits; Is the device connected to a car kit? what type of motion occurred prior to and after the "stop" (If motion is smooth and fast before and after you are probably in a vehicle).

One thing to be aware of with visit tracking is that you can receive an initial `CLVisit` with just an arrival date and then later get an update with the arrival and departure dates filled in.

You can also expect some latency between when you arrive at a location and when you get the initial `CLVisit` to your delegate, but the arrival date is "back dated" to when iOS determined that the visit started.

Comment: Is there anything specific to configure in the locationManager instance?. Right now, I just create an instance, set a delegate and once I get the always permission, I call startMonitoringVisits api.

Comment: You need to ensure that you have enabled background location updates and added the background location capability to your app.  You should also instantiate your location manager in `didFinishLaunching` in order to receive visits that were detected while your app wasn't running.  Note that you probably wont get visits after you "swipe up" to kill your app.